# How to put a form tag in this code

Tags: php, html, javascript

I want to put a form tag in this because I want to put input fields in the div

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31856931/5821424

i tried putting a form tag but after i add the form tag the button function doesn't work anymore

Comment: The answer you linked to is at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). That's where you should be posting this question. Programming questions are off-topic here.

Comment: plus.. you should share the code you've tried too. (: